# Error while getting data Using RMI from services into WEB application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, rmi

I am getting following exception while I am trying to get list of tasks, from services that I have written which are supporting hibernate 4, into web application which supports hibernate 3

java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

```
             Services       ------------------>      WEB 
             (Hibernate 4)                           (Hibernate 3)
```

Web trying to get data from services through RMI and getting above excpetion

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your client doesn't see the classes in your service. One of the methods to achieve this is to have a shared rmi code base. Consider following script that adds all jars in the lib folder and your primary jar in the dist folder to rmi codebase and make them visible to the client:

```
#!/bin/bash
lib_path=lib
artefact=name-of-your.jar
for file in $(ls $lib_path); do
 lib=$lib:$lib_path/$file
 rmicodebase="$rmicodebase file:$PWD/$lib_path/$file"
done

lib=$lib:dist/$artefact:etc
rmicodebase="$rmicodebase file:$PWD/dist/$artefact"
CLASSPATH=classes:etc:$lib
echo CLASSPATH: $CLASSPATH
echo rmicodebase=$rmicodebase

java -Xmx64M -Xms64M -classpath $CLASSPATH -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="$rmicodebase" $*
```

I assume that you have a shared rmi registry in the central process of your server. Another possibility to achieve the class visibility is to have a separate rmi registry running in the server process:

```
java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port)
```

and have your client connect to this registry.

regards
Leon

Comment: file: code bases only work if the client has the same view of the relevant file system that the server does. HTTP-based code bases are more usual.